# How to cancel a Parse JSK query

Tags: jquery, parse-platform

I'm using jQuery to initiate a Parse.com Javascript query from a button click. The problem is that if someone clicks the `game-score-button` multiple times in quick succession the list of name will appear multiple times. eg. If they press it twice quickly then it will double up the names.

```
$('#game-score-button').click(function() {
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            // If successful then clear the names from the list        
            $('#name-list').empty();

            // Iterate through the 
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var object = results[i];
                var name = object.get('playerName');
                $('#name-list').append(name);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

I think I need to find a way to cancel an existing query if it exists and then run the new one.

I thought that it would run the query, clear the name-list using the `.empty()` command, then re-populate but this doesn't appear to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to disable the button when user click on it, then enable again in success/error callback.

Comment: Well that just seems sensible! Thanks heaps... simple simple :) I tried a whole bunch of complex silly stuff... Do you want to add as answer?

Comment: Ok.. I'll add an answer. Just don't wanna let people waste their time into solved questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reposted from Comment:**

You need to disable the button when user click on it, then enable again in success/error callback.